# how to get a slot content in the css content property of a pseudo ;:before element (or :;after) in a web component?

Tags: css, web-component, pseudo-element

Well, I think that the question is in the title :
in a web component, with shadowRoot, I want to use a slot text-content inside the content property of a pseudo ::before or ::after element.
This could make me gain much lines.

Would you have an idea, a proposal, a solution ?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: it's not possible without javascript coding

Comment: @ Nathaniel : I have done two versions, tirst one with a CSS variable in the host of the webcomponent, the second with an attribute in the host with javascript propagation during the connectedcallback event of the webcomponent. I'm looking for a reduced code solution.

Comment: @ Supersharp: Too bad, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lamplightdev

Thank you for your answer.

I was looking for something wich doesn't exist yet.
So I have chose a solution with css var and a setter to set it :

```
class extends HTMLElement {
  set content(val) {
    this.setAttribute('data-content',val);
  }
  constructor() {
...
```

and, of course :

```
:host::before {
  content: attr(data-content);
...
```

This seems to be the lighter solution I may imagine.

**I'd like to suggest to web's standards developpers to create a new css function : slot(name) witch, with attr(...), var(...) and calc(...), could help the use of pseudo elements inside a web component.
Could someone show me the way to present this proposal ???**

I do apologize for my poor english language (I'm french, nobdy's perfect).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the use of CSS custom properties as the source for the `content` of `::before` and `::after` and the `slotchange` event:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>WC</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script>
      class XTest extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super();

          // add shadow dom and insert template content
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });

          const template = document.getElementById("x-test-template");
          const templateContent = template.content;

          shadowRoot.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
        }

        connectedCallback() {
          // get all the named slots
          const slots = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("slot[name]");

          [...slots].forEach(slot => {
            // add a listener to run when the slot changes
            slot.addEventListener("slotchange", event => {
              // get the slot name
              const name = event.target.name;
              
              // get the slot content
              const text = event.target.assignedNodes()[0].textContent;

              // update the custom property
              this.style.setProperty(`--content-${name}`, `'${text}'`);
            });
          });
        }
      }

      customElements.define("x-test", XTest);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <template id="x-test-template">
      <style>
        :host {
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;

          font-size: 2rem;
          padding: 2rem;
        }

        :host::before,
        :host::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;

          font-size: 1rem;
        }

        :host::before {
          /* set the pseudo selector content to the custom property */
          content: var(--content-before, "");
          left: 0;
        }

        :host::after {
          /* set the pseudo selector content to the custom property */
          content: var(--content-after, "");
          right: 0;
        }

        slot[name] {
          display: none;
        }
      </style>

      <!-- slot for ::before -->
      <slot name="before"></slot>
      
      <!-- default slot -->
      <slot></slot>
      
      <!-- slot for ::after -->
      <slot name="after"></slot>
    </template>

    <x-test>
      <span slot="before">B</span>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <span slot="after">A</span>
    </x-test>
  </body>
</html>
```